# Get the underline to extend out past the text

Tags: css, html

In a table, the `td` tag contains a dynamic text which is underlined so I used the following -

```
<td width="50%" align= "left">
  <span style="font-size:8px;font-weight:bold;">
    <em style="text-decoration: underline;">{TERMINAL}</em><br />
    (HOME OPERATING CENTER AND ADDRESS)
  </span>
</td>
```

but How do I get the underline to extend out past the text, like till the length of the text `(HOME OPERATING CENTER AND ADDRESS)`??

**NOTE:**

I can use `&nbsp;` multiple times to make it equal to the text length but it looks ugly and because my text `{TERMINAL}` length is not fixed so using   can not work to match the length of second text.

Comment: Can't you do it like http://jsfiddle.net/5vKuR/ ?

Comment: It will also underline the second text `(HOME OPERATING CENTER AND ADDRESS)`. I only want to underline the first text which is dynamic and it should be as long as the length of second text.

Comment: @Mr.Alien - Check out this for the desired output- http://jsfiddle.net/5vKuR/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've cleaned up the code a bit and replaced your

```
<em> with <p>
```

[**Fiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fj3RE/)

Explanation: A paragraph's default width is 100% of its container. By using the border-bottom styling, you'll have way more control over how the "underline" looks in terms of color, thickness, etc...

Removing the span was just a kneejerk reaction, but I suppose there could have a been a "good" reason for it. Adding it back and taking the style off the table cell won't affect the underline solution.  ;)

Comment: Didn't think of that! I like that better than my solution.

Comment: That's indeed a nice and clean solution, I'd go with that. But from time to time a well-placed `<hr>` is also good to keep in mind. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can fake the underline with an < hr >:

http://jsfiddle.net/ntwiles/5vKuR/4/

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <em>{TERMINAL}</em><hr id='underline' /><br />
            (HOME OPERATING CENTER AND ADDRESS)
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

#underline
{
    margin-top:0;
    margin-left:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Together with the above solutions you have several options, two of them I placed in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/boldewyn/LaFXd/):

1. Use `line-height` and `text-decoration:overline` on the lower text:

   *Advantage:* The underlining doesn't fill the complete table cell but only the actual text in question

   *Disadvantage:* Very fragile. Will break, when the `line-height` doesn't match to bring under- and overlining to match, or when one of both texts starts to extend on more than one line.
2. Use `display:block`: This is basically the same as @Frankenscarf's answer. It just doesn't need markup change, but if that's no concern, I'd go with his answer and change the tag.

Answer (score 0):

In this code also try

```
<body>
<td width="50%" align= "left">
  <span style="font-size:8px;font-weight:bold;">
    <em style="text-decoration: underline;">{TERMINAL}</em><br />
<p style="text-decoration:underline" >   (HOME OPERATING CENTER AND ADDRESS)</p>
  </span>
</td>
</body>
```